# Is it possible to a get a list of the currently defined functions in a powershell runspace?

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I know that I can get the commands that were defined *initially* by using something like:

```cs
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.InitialSessionsState.Commands
```

or in PowerShell itself:

```psh
[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace.InitialSessionState.Commands
```

But this only represents the state before the runspace was created.

If I import a module (even by manually creating the session state object and using `sesh.ImportPSModule()` before the runspace is opened), none of those functions or cmdlets will show up in the list.

Same thing if I define a new function with `.AddScript()` or something.

Is there any way to get the *current state* of the runspace rather than just the initial state, from outside the runspace?

I thought about just invoking `Get-Command` from inside the runspace and returning the objects, but it seems.. wrong to me for some reason. I feel like I'm missing something simple here, and there should be a way to just look at the current state and what's defined in it.

Answer (score 2):

Does the function PSProvider work for your needs?

```
Get-ChildItem function:
```

Comment: This is basically the same as using `Get-Command`, which is fine, but it would have to be run inside the runspace. I am trying to get the current list of commands from *outside* the runspace.

Answer (score 1):

`Runspace` have `SessionStateProxy` property, which allows you to interact with `Runspace` `SessionState`:

```
$PowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$PowerShell.AddScript{
    function SomeFunction {}
    function SomeOtherFunction {}
}.Invoke()

$PowerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.InvokeCommand.GetCommands('*','Function',$true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to try this out yet since I stopped working on this project a while ago. I'm not sure if/when I will start again but I will definitely check next time I'm doing this kind of thing.